# dictionary from different lists python 3

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have the following lists:

```py
list1 = ["Hulk", "Flash", "Tesla"]
list2 = ["green", "23", "thunder"]
list3 = ["Marvel", "DC_comics", "0.0"]
```

and I would like to create a dictionary like this one:

```py
{
    "eo:dict": [
        {"name": "Hulk", "color": green, "company": Marvel},
        {"name": "Flash", "color": red, "company": DC_comics},
        {"name": "Tesla", "color": thunder, "company": 0.0},
    ]
}
```

that has to be appended in a specific position within a json file I'm creating.

I tried in this way:

```py
keys = ["name", "company", "colours"]
eo_dict = dict(zip(keys, name,company, color))
```

but I got the error `"_ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required_"`

Could anybody give me some hints?

Comment: How did you get `"color":red` ? Your expected dictionary has SyntaxError.

Comment: This can also be done using pandas by converting it to a data frame and then to dictionary as records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to get the expected output:

```
list1 = ['Hulk', 'Flash', 'Tesla']
list2 = ['green', '23', 'thunder']
list3 = ['Marvel', 'DC_comics', '0.0']
keys = ['name', 'color', 'company']

out = list(dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[{'name': 'Hulk', 'color': 'green', 'company': 'Marvel'},
 {'name': 'Flash', 'color': '23', 'company': 'DC_comics'},
 {'name': 'Tesla', 'color': 'thunder', 'company': '0.0'}]
```

To export as JSON:

```
import json

jd = json.dumps([{'eo:dict': out}], indent=4)
print(jd)

# Output
[
    {
        "eo:dict": [
            {
                "name": "Hulk",
                "color": "green",
                "company": "Marvel"
            },
            {
                "name": "Flash",
                "color": "23",
                "company": "DC_comics"
            },
            {
                "name": "Tesla",
                "color": "thunder",
                "company": "0.0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Corralien thanks a lot! It works!!
what if I have to insert this JSON section in a specific point of an existing JSON file I'm creating? I hope my question is clear

Comment: Load the json file as a python data type, insert your dict at the right place then convert back your data structure as json file.

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this one,**

```
keys = ["name", "age", "location"]
values = ["John", 28, "New York"]

my_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}

print(my_dict)
```

**The output is like**

{'name': 'John', 'age': 28, 'location': 'New York'}